# Terraform: configure AWS Lambda log format setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In the AWS console there is an option to change the lambda log format between text and JSON under Configuration > Monitoring and operations tools > Logging configuration > Log format. It appears to be defaulting to Text and I want to update it to JSON for all my lambda functions. The functions are currently completely managed with Terraform but I don't see any option in the provider documentation for this setting in Terraform. Am I missing something or does Terraform not support this setting? Any other options besides something like explicitly setting it using the API?

I reviewed terraform provider lambda documentation and terraform provider cloudwatch log group documentation. I did not find any relevant settings.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon added this log configuration feature to AWS Lambda [only 5 days ago](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/aws-lambda-controls-search-filter-aggregate-lambda-function-logs/). The Terraform AWS Provider does not support this new feature yet. There is an issue you can upvote and track [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/34455), to add the feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `awscc` provider for that, it seems it is already [available](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#nested-schema-for-logging_config):

> `application_log_level` (String) Application log granularity level, can only be used when LogFormat is set to JSON

> `log_format` (String) Log delivery format for the lambda function

> `log_group` (String) The log group name.

> `system_log_level` (String) System log granularity level, can only be used when LogFormat is set to JSON